# Ordering of events in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, onblur

So you'll see below that I have two components, an AutocompleteUsers card dropdown, and an input field. When the user clicks inside of the AutocompleteUsers card, this triggers chooseUserInAutocomplete, which changes state. So good so far.

When users click outside of the input field (onBlur) I hide the AutocompleteUsers card (toggleAutocomplete). The problem is when I click inside of the AutocompleteUsers card, it also triggers the onBlur before chooseUserInAutocomplete is even triggered.

One way to solve this is with `setTimeout`, but I don't really like that approach because it feels finicky. What's the best solution here?

```
toggleAutocomplete() {
    this.setState({ autocompleteIsVisible: !this.state.autocompleteIsVisible });
}

chooseUserInAutocomplete = (username: string) => {
    this.setState({ guessAuthor: username });
}

<AutocompleteUsers 
    visible = { this.state.autocompleteIsVisible }
    searchString = { this.state.guessAuthor }
    chooseUser = { this.chooseUserInAutocomplete }
/>
<input 
    type="text" 
    ref={ e => { if (e) this.guess = e } }
    name="guess"
    onChange={ (e) => this.setState({ guessAuthor: e.target.value})}
    onFocus={ () => this.toggleAutocomplete() }
    onBlur={ () => this.toggleAutocomplete() }
    value={ this.state.guessAuthor }
/>
```

Comment: if you want to allow the users to use the autoComplete, why do you hide it when the input is not focused ?

Comment: @klugjo It's how autocomplete usually works. For example, type anything in Chrome's URL bar. Notice how when you click off, the autocomplete disappears.

Comment: Ok so the input is your autocomplete input. Then why don't you call your `chooseUserInAutocomplete` function directly in the onBlur of the input ?

Comment: So I want onBlur to trigger when the user clicks off of the card, or enters a different input field. I don't want the card to stay there as they are working on something else. So for that use case, I don't want chooseUserInAutocomplete to trigger. However, I do want chooseUserInAutocomplete if they actually clicked on something inside the card (or use a keyboard shortcut to select it).